# Python Datetime Showing one day ahead date

Tags: python, django, timezone, pytz

I encountered one weird issue. I have one Django project, which uses (America/Denver) timezone by default.

I got a couple of records into the database.

```
id   name   date_create
1    foo    Dec. 8, 2020, 6:15 p.m. 
2    bar    Dec. 1, 2020, 8:28 p.m.
```

When I print the above record, it behaves weirdly.

```
>>> print(record_one.date_create.date())
>>> Dec. 9, 2020 
>>> print(record_one.date_create)
>>> Dec. 8, 2020, 6:15 p.m.

>>> print(record_two.date_create.date())
>>> Dec. 2, 2020
>>> print(record_one.date_create)
>>> Dec. 1, 2020, 8:28 p.m.
```

I am using python 3.5 and Django2

Django setting

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Denver'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

Comment: Which DB you are using?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu postgresql on aws server

Comment: I am almost certain that the `record_one.date_create` will return the `__str__` representation of the ***DateTime*** object which will look like `2020-12-11 01:00:00+00:00`. So, the last ***`+00.00`*** indicates that the retuned time in **UTC** and not in ***`TIME_ZONE`***

Comment: afaik, Django will save the time in UTC (and IMHO, it is the best practice) and it will convert to XYZ timezone whenever required.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behaviour as explained in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-TIME_ZONE):

> When USE_TZ is True, this is the default time zone that Django will use to display datetimes in templates and to interpret datetimes entered in forms.

So the value retrieved from the database is an aware datetime with tzinfo set to UTC. The template tag can then use `astimezone` (via `timezone.template_localtime` -> `timezone.localtime`) to convert it. However, you're calling date on the field value.

To emulate the template behaviour we can do the following:

```
from django.utils.timezone import template_localtime
import datetime
import pytz
denver = pytz.timezone("America/Denver")
utc = pytz.timezone("UTC")
denver_dt = datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 18, 15, microsecond=0, tzinfo=denver)
utc_dt = denver_dt.astimezone(utc)
template_localtime(utc_dt)
Out[9]: datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 18, 15, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/Denver' MST-1 day, 17:00:00 STD>)
template_localtime(utc_dt).date()
Out[10]: datetime.date(2020, 12, 8)
```

So with your variables:

```py
print(template_localtime(record_one.date_create).date())
```

Comment: You've confused the `TIME_ZONE` setting (which the OP referenced) with the database-specific `'TIME_ZONE` that's part of the `DATABASES` setting (which is the documentation you referenced).

Comment: Indeed I did. Thanks.